# APACHE TOMCAT 1.4 AND JDK 1.4

Tags: mysql, apache, jdk1.4

I HAVE APACHE TOMCAT 1.4 WHERE DO I PUT MYSQL DRIVER

Answer (score 0):

if you're doing it as `DriverManager.getConnection()`, then you can put the mysql connector jar in `Tomcat/lib` or `YourApp/WEB-INF/lib`